# Credential Manager has been disabled by Administrator and cannot re-enable

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, credentials

I'm having trouble getting a Windows 7 work computer to keep credentials for a mapped drive.  Whenever I load Credential Manager, I get "Windows Credentials have been disabled by your Administrator."  I'm logged into an Administrator account (but not the built-in account), and haven't had much luck removing this restriction.

The computer is not on a domain, so there is no domain policy enforcing this.  I checked gpedit.msc, and looked under:

> Computer > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options

I found the option Network Access:  Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication, but it is already disabled.  I performed this check on both the server and user computer.

I made sure it is in the same work group as all of the other computers.  I tried CCleaner to see if maybe there was a registry issue, but it just found missing .DLLs and unnecessary file types.

I was trying VaultCMD in Command Prompt, and created a new Vault, but I don't have the proper option to store the credentials for the server.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this question and telling us about `Computer > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options -> Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication`. In my case, it was set to `Enabled`. Setting it to disabled immediately solved the problem which was driving me mad for several month, that is, Windows 10 forgetting the network credentials in at least 10 VMs and physical machines I regularly deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the ADMX templates for your version of Windows, and track down the policy in question. There is an XLS spreadsheet in the ADMX download that gives all info in the templates, including Registry location. It will be a handy reference when you inevitably find "other things" that have been set via registry.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to locate the cause by running a gpresult report from the command line or Powershell prompts:

```
GPRESULT /H GPReport.html
```

That will generate a html report in the working directory which should list polices that are configured outside of the default configuration.